# How to create a SideNav with animated tabs using MaterializeCSS?

Tags: css, jquery-animate, material-design, materialize

I want to change my web app to material design and I included Materialize CSS into my project. I changed my old menu to something like this

```
<div class="col s12">
  <ul class="tabs">
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#test1">Tab1</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a class="active" href="#test2">Tab2</a></li>
    <li class="tab col s4"><a href="#test3">Tab3</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="test1" class="col s12">Test 1</div>
<div id="test2" class="col s12">Test 2</div>
<div id="test3" class="col s12">Test 3</div>
```

The text section has no animation like the .tab .indicator element.
I tried with onclick="Materialize.showStaggeredList('#test2') for a transition but it doesn't work. Is there some support for this type of transition ?

Comment: if I understand it correctly, you probably are missing the `materialize.min.js` dependancy in your project which is required along-side `materialize.min.css`. Take a look at this **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/8ntfp5xj/)** and take a look at the `External Resources`.

Comment: the animation i want to trigger is for the test area <div id="test1" ...Test3</div> which the tabs refer...even in your example Test1 Test2 and Test 3 interchanges without the animation specific to android material design (it doesn't slides)

Comment: are you looking for something like **[this](http://jsfiddle.net/tahirahmed/8ntfp5xj/1/)**?

Comment: @TahirAhmed thanks a lot, this is what i was searching for... now i understand how to use UL with .showStaggeredList

Comment: no worries. Glad I could help. :)